how to run an interactive kotlin program on command line
sample code can be found at https://github.com/KyleMcB/demo
I can't figure out how to run a kotlin jvm application on the command line. Intelli J will run it in it's built in shell with interactive, but I want to distribute this as a command line program. so the program is just trying to use readln()
package com.xingpeds

fun main() {
    val name = readln()
    println("Hello, " + name + "!")
}

and the build file
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.20"
    application
}
application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
group = "com.xingpeds"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(19)
}

when I use ./gradlew run I get
euclid@kyles-MBP-3 ~/D/democli (main)> ./gradlew clean run

> Task :run FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainKt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Users/euclid/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-19.0.2/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 545ms
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

when I try to run the script in the build folder I get
euclid@kyles-MBP-3 ~/D/democli (main)> build/scripts/democli
Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainKt

How can I run a jvm command line application?

Please show the entire Main.kt file and your build.gradle.kts. Your question should be self-contained. I should not need to visit an external site.

@sweeper updated with whole Main.kt and build.gradle.kts

The problem is here:
mainClass.set("MainKt")

You are supposed to write the fully-qualified name of your main class here, but you only wrote its simple name MainKt. Your main class is in the package com.xingpeds, so its fully-qualified name is com.xingpeds.MainKt.
mainClass.set("com.xingpeds.MainKt")

Since you are reading from stdin, you also need
tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}

in your build.gradle.kts for readln to work correctly with gradle run. (See also)

To run the generated class file in the build folder directly, go to build/classes/kotlin/main, and run
kotlin com.xingpeds.MainKt


Thanks a ton for your help, but didn't quite work. gradlew run changed Exception in thread "main" kotlin.io.ReadAfterEOFException: EOF has already been reached so gradlew knows how to execute it. Although I'd love if gradle would run it interactively, but the script in the build folder still fails. Error: Could not find or load main class com.xingpeds.MainKt

@KyleM Ah your code is reading input from stdin - I forgot about that. See this post. As for "the script in the build folder", I don't see a script being generated in the build folder. What are you talking about?
